# Does Mathematica 11 work on macOS High Sierra (v10.13)?

Tags: mac-os-x, compatibility

In *Mathematica*, I see the following information

```
$Version
```

> 11.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 16, 2017)

However, in the macOS *System Information* app seems to indicate that *Mathematica* v11.1 is not 64-bit

> [image]

- Will Mathematica run on macOS v10.13?
- Which bugs or issues exist?

Comment: I have MMA 11.2.0 installed and running on Mac OS X 10.13.  No problems whatsoever.

Comment: 32-bit programs *do run* on macOS 10.13.  On macOS, the Mathematica kernel is 64-bit while the Front End is currently still 32-bit. These run as two separate processes.

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica is more or less as compatible with High Sierra as it is with Sierra. Old versions (8 and ealier) require the old Java 1.6 JRE, which I'm not sure is being made available for High Sierra.

The only known issues at this time are that the "Options" button in the Open and Save dialogs has a habit of disappearing.  It's still there and works, but you may need to click around and/or resize the window to find it.  We are working on a fix for this issue.