# Running Mathematica 10.3 on OS X 10.13.0 or 10.13.1, High Sierra?

Tags: version-10, mac-os-x, compatibility

Has anyone had success running Mathematica 10.3 on OS X 10.13.0 / 10.13.1 / High Sierra?

If anyone has used (or is currently using) this combination did it appear to work successively?  Were there any particular issues you encountered that suggested compatibility issues?

[Does Mathematica 11 work on macOS High Sierra (v10.13)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156431/does-mathematica-11-work-on-macos-high-sierra-v10-13)

Comment: All versions of Mathematica 8 and above run on my High Sierra machine.  But, I'm experiencing major sluggishness of the front end with all of them, including 11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version
(* "10.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 9, 2015)" *)

Import["!sw_vers", "Text"]
(* "ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13
BuildVersion:   17A365" *)
```

I haven't noticed any malfunctions, although I don't usually use this *Mathematica* version.  I do notice the "Options" button missing from the "Open" dialog box, just as Itai mentioned in the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version
(*"10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"*)

Import["!sw_vers", "Text"]
(*"ProductName: Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.3
BuildVersion:   17D47"*)
```

I have not run 10.3, but Mathematica 10.4.1 very successfully on OS X 10.13.3. In fact, *ALL* of my problems with Mathematica 11.1 and 11.2 have gone away, as did the sluggishness of the frontend. In summary, going way back to Mathematica 10.4.1, I can work again without chasing after work-arounds to prop up the bug-bag that is Mathematica 11.x.